# How can I split a file up by matching lines context?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a file, `x`, with section delimiters:

```
The first section

#!

The second section

#!

The third section
```

And I want to split it up into a sequence of separate files, like:

```
The first section
```

```
#!

The second section
```

```
#!

The third section
```

I thought `csplit` would be the solution, with a command-line something like:

```
$ csplit -sk x '/#!/' {9999}
```

But the second file (`xx01`) ends up containing both delimiters:

```
#!

The second section

#!
```

Any ideas for how to accomplish what I want in a POSIX compliant way? (Yes, I could reach for Perl/Python/Ruby and friends; but, the point is to stretch my shell knowledge.)

---

I worry that I've found a bug in OSX csplit. Can people give the following a go and let me know the results?

```
#!/bin/sh

test -e

work="$(basename $0).$RANDOM"
mkdir $work

csplit -sk -f "$work/" - '/#/' '{9999}' <<EOF
First
#
Second
#
Third
EOF

if [ $(grep -c '#' $work/01) -eq 2 ]; then
  echo FAIL Repeat
else
  echo PASS Repeat
fi

rm $work/*

csplit -sk -f "$work/" - '/#/' '/#/' <<EOF
First
#
Second
#
Third
EOF

if [ $(grep -c '#' $work/01) -eq 2 ]; then
  echo FAIL Exact
else
  echo PASS Exact
fi

uname -a
```

When I run it on my Snow Leopard box, I get:

```
$ ./csplit-test
csplit: #: no match
FAIL Repeat
PASS Exact
Darwin lani.bigpond 11.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.2.0: Tue Aug  9 20:54:00 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1699.24.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

And on my Debian box, I get:

```
$ sh ./csplit-test 
csplit: `/#/': match not found on repetition 2
PASS Repeat
PASS Exact
```

Comment: Testing this out using your exact setup gives me the result you're looking for.  I'm using `csplit (GNU coreutils) 8.5`

Comment: That's bad. I'm using OSX csplit.

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work for me on LINUX:

```
csplit -sk filename '/#!/' {*}
```

giving:

```
$ more xx00
The first section

$ more xx01
#!

The second section

$ more xx02
#!

The third section
```

you could also use Ruby or Perl to do this in a tiny script, and get rid of the delimiters all together

---

on Fedora 13 Linux:

```
$ ./test.sh 
csplit: `/#/': match not found on repetition 2
PASS Repeat
PASS Exact
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.34.8-68.fc13.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Feb 17 15:03:58 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I just added a test. Can you run it and let me know the results?

Answer (score 1):

Uh oh. (FreeBSD 8.1 install running in a Parallels VM)

```
src ./test_split.sh
csplit: #: no match
FAIL Repeat
PASS Exact
FreeBSD <hostname> 8.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE #0: Mon Jul 19 02:55:53 UTC 2010 root@almeida.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC i386
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not ideal, but you can do something like this with `awk`.

**Your file:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat f0
The first section

#!

The second section

#!

The third section
```

Get everything before `#!` using this (you can redirect this in a file)

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/#!/{exit;}1' f0 
The first section
```

Get `#!` followed by the content and split before the next `#!`.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '/^#!/{x++}{print >(x".txt")}' f0
[jaypal:~/Temp] ls *.txt
1.txt 2.txt
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat 1.txt 
#!

The second section

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat 2.txt 
#!

The third section
```

You might get an easy way around with `perl` using something like this -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/;
$_ = <>;
$n = 0;

for $match (split(/(?=#!)/)) {
      open(O, '>temp' . ++$n);
      print O $match;
      close(O);
}
```

**Files created by script:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp1 
The first section

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp2 
#!

The second section

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat temp3 
#!

The third section
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *awk* and testing it in a linux machine:

My version of *awk*:

```
$ awk --version | head -1
GNU Awk 4.0.0
```

Content of *infile*:

```
$ cat infile
The first section

#!

The second section

#!

The third section
```

Content of the *awk* script:

```
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN {
        ## Set 'Input Record Separator' variable.
        RS = "#!";
}

{
        ## Set an integer variable as output file name.
        ++filenum;
}

## For first section.
FNR == 1 {
        ## Remove leading and trailing spaces.
        sub( /^\s+/, "", $0);
        sub( /\s+$/, "", $0);

        ## Print to output file.
        printf "%s\n", $0 > filenum ".txt"
}

## For sections from second one to last one.
FNR > 1 {
        ## Remove trailing spaces.
        sub( /\s+$/, "", $0);

        ## Print to output file.
        printf "%s%s\n", RS, $0 > filenum ".txt"
}
```

Running the script:

```
$ awk -f script.awk infile
```

Check output:

```
$ ls [0-9].txt
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
$ cat 1.txt 
The first section
$ cat 2.txt 
#!

The second section
$ cat 3.txt 
#!

The third section
```